# Gcloud app deploy gives unsupported Python 2.5 runtime error

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, windows-10-desktop

When I run `gcloud app deploy` in my project folder I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Service [None] uses unsupported Python 2.5 runtime. Please use [runtime: python27] instead.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Errors occurred while parsing the App Engine app configuration.
```

But I highly doubt that I have any 2.5 version related stuff. It's rather old version.

My app.yaml says:

```
runtime: python

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

According to https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/08/python-3-on-Google-App-Engine-flexible-environment-now-in-beta.html Python 3 should be available. Or is it not at the moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing part was `env: flex`

So, the right yaml file should look like this:

```
runtime: python
threadsafe: yes
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two avenues forward here. For the [Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime) flavor, yes, you need to specify the key as stated.

However, when you don't specify the `env` key, then you default into into the [Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime) environment, and in this environment, you need to specify the version directly on the runtime, ala, `runtime: python38`.